# nextTriggerDate() doesn't return the 'expected' value, is there another way to obtain the next fire date of a repeating Local Notification?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, uilocalnotification

In my application I allow users to schedule repeating Local Notifications. The issue that I have though (any many others based on looking around) is that nextTriggerDate() always bases its return value on the current time rather than the time at which the notification was scheduled. I've seen suggestions to store a "date" value in the userInfo of the notification but seeing as how the notifications repeat, it doesn't seem like it would be able to keep this date value accurate each time the notification fires. Is there any way to get the actual fire date of a repeating local notification?

```
func getNotifications(completion: @escaping (Bool)->()){
    notificationArray.removeAll()

    center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
        print("Count: \(notifications.count)")
        if notifications.count <= 0{
            completion(true)
            return
        }
        for item in notifications {
            var nextTrigger = Date()

            if let trigger = item.trigger as? UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger{

                nextTrigger = trigger.nextTriggerDate()!

            }else if let trigger = item.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger{

                nextTrigger = trigger.nextTriggerDate()!
            }
        }
    }
    completion(true)
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've updated my question with the code I'm using. As an example, if I schedule a repeating 2 minute notification then call this function, the nextTrigger variables return the current time + the time interval of the notification. This is not the actual date at which the notification fires though. What I expect/want is to be able to get the time/date at which the notification will actually fire based on the time/date it was originally scheduled. I'm not sure why nextTriggerDate() doesn't return this but after doing some research it seems like others have had this problem as well. Thanks!!

Comment: I think this is either a bug or a documentation bug. The documentation says it should be the trigger date of the notification associsted with the trigger, but the trigger does not seem to have a reference to a notification, and what would be the result if you created a trigger and had not yet associated it with a notification?  So it seems likely that the documentation is wrong and this function actually returns the next fire date if it it was used to schedule a notification "now". I think you should probably raise a bug with Apple and see what they say

Comment: I actually ended up sending an email to Apple a few hours ago, still waiting for a reply. It's definitely odd that they'd implement it this way so hopefully it's most likely a bug. Thanks for the help! I'll add a comment/reply once they get back to me.

Comment: This seems like a genuine bug, but the way to report it is not "an email". You should file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: @Paulw11 His code wasn't very clear, perhaps, but see the code and results in my answer, below. I think this is a genuine bug (and from the sound of it, well known and long standing).

Comment: It isn't a matter of "more useful", @Paulw11. With this bug, `nextTriggerDate()` isn't any use _at all_. The result that it gives is simply wrong and there's no way to get the right result (i.e. to learn what time we will in fact next fire).

Comment: Will do, thanks for the explanation below. I should've been more in depth with my code/question. In the previous comment I meant an email but through the developer portal. I used 1 of my 2 developer support requests so hopefully they'll actually respond. Will also submit the bug report to that website. Thanks for confirming this once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed. I ran this code:

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 120, repeats: true)
print("scheduling at", Date())
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+15) {
    print("checking at", Date())
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests {
        arr in let arr = arr
        if let req = arr[0].trigger as? UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger {
            let fd = req.nextTriggerDate()
            print("trigger date", fd as Any)
        }
    }
}
// ... proceed to configure and schedule the notification
```

I also configured my user notification center delegate to receive the notification in the foreground and print the time.

Here's what I saw in the console:

```
scheduling at 2018-08-01 03:40:36 +0000
checking at 2018-08-01 03:40:51 +0000
trigger date Optional(2018-08-01 03:42:51 +0000)
received notification while active 2018-08-01 03:42:36 +0000
```

So the trigger date was reported as 2 minutes from *when I checked*, but the notification actually fired 2 minutes from *when I scheduled it*.

I'd describe that as a bug!

The one disagreement I'd have with your original question is that I get exactly the same result for a *non*-repeating UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger:

```
scheduling at 2018-08-01 03:45:50 +0000
checking at 2018-08-01 03:46:06 +0000
trigger date Optional(2018-08-01 03:48:06 +0000)
received notification while active 2018-08-01 03:47:50 +0000
```

A UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger also has a `timeInterval` property, but even that does us no good unless we know when the notification was originally scheduled — and a UNNotificationRequest provides no way to find that out.

(Just to be certain, I postponed my checking until the repeating notification had fired a couple of times, but the result was the same: `nextTriggerDate` is clearly adding the `timeInterval` to *now* rather than reporting the time at which the notification will next fire.)

Comment: This bug still exists in iOS 14.

Comment: This bug still exists in iOS 15.

Comment: @Cuneyt I'm not supposed to use a comment to say "thank you", but thank you. :) I filed a bug on this long ago; I'll add a note to that bug report.